# How to convert a Document Instance to a FileStream

Tags: c#, wcf, interop, ms-word, filestream

I've Been struggling with this in the past hour.

Can someone help me to convert an instance of Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Document to FileStream? I have this function below which does not work but might help you guys to have an idea of what im trying to do:

```
 using System;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 using System.Linq;
 using System.Runtime.Serialization;
 using System.ServiceModel;
 using System.Text;
 using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word;
 using System.IO;

 namespace DropDownTemplate.Web.WebServices.Word
 {
     // NOTE: You can use the "Rename" command on the "Refactor" menu to change the class name "WordGenerator" in code, svc and config file together.
     public class WordGenerator : IDocumentGenerator
     {
         FileStream IDocumentGenerator.GenerateDocument()
         {
             // For optional parameters create a missing object
             object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
             // open the document specified in the fileName variable
             Document adoc = new Document();
             adoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"http://localhost:2014/Resources/MG.PNG", ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);
             using (StreamReader y = new StreamReader())
             {
                 y.Read(adoc);   
             }
             return adoc;
         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: not sure to understand what you want to do. You have a document, and you want to get its content in binary ?

Comment: Sorry with the code dude just a newbie here :(... I want to create a word document and send it back to the web service in FileStream Format....

Comment: never did it, but the probable solution is : 1. Generate the document as you did. 2. Save it to a temp file 3. Return the content of the temp file. I'm not sure you can return a FileStream directly, unless you set up your service to use streaming.

Comment: Uhmmm isnt converting the documents to a temp file could be very risky. specially this would run on the server.

Comment: Does the document class provides a save method that accept a stream as argument ? Can you move to a pure OpenXml generation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this should work:

```
 public class WordGenerator : IDocumentGenerator
 {
         FileStream IDocumentGenerator.GenerateDocument()
         {
                object missing = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;
                Document adoc = new Document();
                adoc.InlineShapes.AddPicture(@"http://localhost:2014/Resources/MG.PNG", ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                // save the doc file
                object fileName = Path.GetTempFileName();
                adoc.SaveAs(ref fileName, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing, ref missing);

                // quit word and release COM objects
                object saveChanges = WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges;
                adoc.Application.Quit(ref saveChanges, ref missing, ref missing);
                Marshal.ReleaseComObject(adoc);

                // return the stream
                return new FileStream((string)fileName, FileMode.Open);

         }
 }
```

and you'll have to delete the temp file sometime in the future.

Comment: @AllanChua - if you have Office 2010, yes, just pass WdSaveFormat.wdFormatPDF as the FileFormat argument to SaveAs.

Answer (score 1):

You muse save the document to the file system and then read that into a MemoryStream. I don't think serialization would be an option here because Document class is not Serializable probably.